# Div won't wrap around contents in Firefox

Tags: html, css

I can't get the container to correctly wrap around the video in firefox. Chrome and IE work fine. This is the site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id="video_container">
            <video id="trailers" poster="poster.jpg">
                <source src="vLast.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                <source src="vLast.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>
            <nav>
               <div id="controls">
                    <button id="playButton">Play</button>
                    <div id="vol" onclick="showSlider()">Vol
                        <div id="containSlider"> 
                            <input type="range" id="vSlider" min="0" max="1" step="0.1" value="0.5"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>      
                    <div id="defaultBar">
                        <div id="progressBar"></div>
                    </div>

                    <button id="mute">Mute</button>
                    <button id="full" onclick="toggleFullScreen()">Full</button>
               </div> 
               <div id="playlist" class="animated fadeInRight">
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb1"><img src="TbGow.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vGow')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb2"><img src="TbLast.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vLast')"/></div>
                    <div class="thumb" id="tb3"><img src="TbTwo.jpg" onClick="changeTrailer('vTwo')"/></div>
               </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#video_container{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1; 
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    border:5px solid black;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;   
}
#video_container video{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: why do you have a lot of mozilla specific definitions like `moz-box` ?

Comment: My prof wants them. It's HTML5/CSS3 so some rules won't work without browser prefix.

Comment: fyi, `box` is obsolete.  the current version of the spec has been redesigned and is now called `flexbox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright then Batman :)

Try this

```
<style>
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
     #video_container{
        min-height:1px;
        max-height:1px;
      }
    }
</style>
```

Add this in your html document!

Comment: inline block doesn't work and adds a little bit of space below the video in chrome.

Comment: Wasn't sure if you wanted everything. So I put everything: http://jsfiddle.net/P6t8H/3/

Comment: I dont know if it's normal but the videos won't play in JSFiddle. Here's the sit though. And the code is the same as the Fiddle. http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/video.html

Comment: Yea basically. I can't have the wrapper be larger than the video itself. It works well in Chrome just not Firefox

Comment: Yea sorry I meant the video container. It is the same size in image you posted, so that's good. That's what Im trying to do. The way my code is right now it looks like in the picture I posted above which is pretty bad.

Comment: Just tried it but in Chrome the playlist div no longer shows up. In Firefox the controls no longer show up and yea flex is gone. http://jumpshare.com/v/FV4tne?b=h7kkhW

Comment: I'd have to zoom out to see the entire video, the controls are displaced, and flex is broken.

Comment: I might just have to use a fixed height with a black background and try to make things look nice. It seems too complicated to get the container to wrap around it's contents (the video).

Comment: Damn it. I set the height fixed at 330px but it still does the same thing in Firefox. So annoying.

Comment: I have a Moz-box on my wrapper already. I haven't updated the site. Im looking at it through my editor.

Comment: Can you show me whwat you have or update ur answer because It's not working for me. Im not sure if i have exactly what you have

Comment: Your solution works perfectly in FF but Chrome is now messed up. If there's a way to apply CSS differently per browser I dont mind doing it like that and being done with this problem.

Answer (score 1):

FYI Mozilla Firefox is the only browser that still doesn't support flex-wrap. It supports inly single-line flexbox. (flex-wrap needs multi-line flexbox).

Feature Firefox (Gecko) 
- Not supported
Chrome
- 21.0-webkit
Internet Explorer 
- 10.0-moz
Opera
- full support 12.10
Maxthon
- full support 4.0

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/flex-wrap

I am currently looking for solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try `@-moz-document url-prefix()`, which is a Gecko layout engine rule. Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Reference/Mozilla_Extensions). Enjoy.

Comment: I reformatted your question and added a useful link. I suggest you take a look at the changes. Welcome to Stack Overflow! :)